# Least squares estimation of regression parameters

Tags: regression, estimation

> Let us consider the regression model: $y_i=ax_i+bz_i+abu_i+e_i$ ($1\leq i\leq n$) where $e_i$ are iid mean 0, same variance random errors. Obtain the least squares estimates of $a$ and $b$.

So I think I can proceed simply by minimising $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-ax_i-bz_i-abu_i)^2$.

The normal equations are $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+bu_i)(y_i-ax_i-bz_i-abu_i)=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n (z_i+au_i)(y_i-ax_i-bz_i-abu_i)=0$

But how then can I estimate $a$ and $b$? Is it necessary to solve this system? But it will have multiple solutions. Further, it is difficult to solve.

Comment: One straightforward avenue of investigation would be to set $c=ab$ and introduce Lagrange multipliers.